# Mapping sessions with username in spring boot with redis

Tags: spring-security, redis, spring-boot

How to map the session id with the username, I am using spring boot with redis for storing the sessions.

I would like to ensure that the session key generated by spring boot with redis should be used for the particular user operations only.